# unwanted (transparent) "border" around UITableView when (programmatically) placed in UINavigationControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

On selecting a cell in a UITableView (which itself is placed on the rootView of a UINavigationController) I push a new SubviewController (which has another TableView as its view) onto the NavigationController.
It all works fine, but when it gets displayed it has a transparent Border around it (the same width on all the sides).

I have no Idea what the problem could be. I'm using the same CustomTableCells as in said rootView and if I look at the Properties of the TableView in IB, the Settings are the same as the ones of the UITableView that sits in the rootView of my UINavigationController...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my own problem...
was instantiating said subViewController with a style instead of just calling init...

```
StationProgramsController *progViewController = [[StationProgramsController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

^^left a blank border around my UTTableView^^

```
StationProgramsController *progViewController = [[StationProgramsController alloc] init];
```

^^no border anymore with the above code^^

sorry

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use initWithStyle: UITableViewStylePlain, so that any tableViewController-specific stuff still gets called.